# Android Studio: Save URLS from a URL to an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I am trying to have Android Studio read a text file from a URL into a string array. Then, use the URLS within Picasso to display a simple gallery. My attempts at achieving this are below.

My `GrabData.java` script:

```
public class GrabData
{
static public String[] LIST = {};
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();

    // The text file.
    String filename = "http://www.example.com/my/website/directory/thefile.txt";

    try
    {
        String[] LIST = rf.readLines(filename);

        for (String line : LIST)
        {
            System.out.println(LIST);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ReadFile : Unable to create "+filename+": "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

My `ReadFile.java` script:

```
public class ReadFile extends Activity
{
public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException
{
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    bufferedReader.close();

    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use a URL in the filename string, it doesn't display any images on the gallery, which is able to load from arrays. I am guessing this method can't read URLS. If anyone has any help on how to get this, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Post your gallery URL also

Comment: `FileReader` can't read file over http, you need `HTTPUrlConnection` to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new MyAsyncFileReader().execute("http://www.example.com/my/website/directory/thefile.txt");

}

public static class MyAsyncFileReader extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String []>
{

    @Override
    protected String [] doInBackground(String... params){
        String url= params[0];
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            URL u= new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            InputStream is= conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(is));
            String line=null;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                lines.add(line);

            }
            br.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        //You will get your string array result here .
        // do whatever operations you want to do

         for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
            Log.e("LOG", strings[i]);
        }
    }

}

}
```

This is how it looks in My Activity . Use similarly in you activity.

My edits: Made the MyAsyncFileReader class public and static to be read through other activities.

Comment: Quick question. What are the imports for this?

Comment: Ok, I have pasted the code with the imports and it shows some errors that are pretty confusing. Errors: Error:(26, 23) error: ';' expected ;;; shows more, but won't let me copy/paste. I can get a screenshot if you want.

Comment: I think i should post the whole code now . Will do that too . :)

Comment: Updated code , please see if it helps. It should not give any errors now.

Comment: Ok, doesn't give any errors now. Tested and shows blank screen (for now). Sorry for asking a ton of questions, but where does the resulting output go?

Comment: :). See updated code and try to print log in onPostExecue method. see logs in logcat .

Comment: Ok, works now. How would I be able to use the `new MyAsyncFileReader().execute("test.com/website.txt");` in a different activity. I have tried importing it. Thanks for all of your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: you can simply  Intent intent= new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key",strings); startActivity(intent);